# nested if for sql results

Tags: java, sql, if-statement, nested

Guys I am struggling to create search queries for a database I am developing but the user choices are so many! I don't know how to filter them out! Do I have to create a different query for EVERY SINGLE choice the user checks? If he wants to search for name only, that's an other query. Name and surname is an other. Age and country is another! I don't know how to do that without writing hundreds of lines of code! I have tried this example but it only works if the user fills every textfield.

```
    private void searchB_actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    query = "SELECT agent_id, name, surname, clearance, user_id, alias, missions, age, country, current_mission FROM agents WHERE " ;

    if (!agentidTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

        query = query + "agent_id = '" + agentidTF.getText() + "' ";
        //System.out.println(query);

        if (!nameTF.getText().isEmpty()) {



            query = query + " AND name = '" + nameTF.getText().toUpperCase() + "' ";
            //System.out.println(query);

            if (!surnameTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

                query = query + " AND surname = '" + surnameTF.getText().toUpperCase() + "' ";
                //System.out.println(query);

                if (clearancebox.getSelectedItem() != "SELECT CLEARANCE") {

                    query =
                            query + " AND clearance = '" + clearancebox.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase() +
                            "' ";
                    //System.out.println(query);

                    if (!useridTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

                        query = query + " AND user_id = '" + useridTF.getText() + "' ";
                        //System.out.println(query);

                        if (!ageTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

                            query = query + " AND age = '" + ageTF.getText() + "' ";
                            //System.out.println(query);

                            if (!aliasTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

                                query = query + " AND alias = '" + aliasTF.getText().toUpperCase() + "' ";
                                //System.out.println(query);

                                if (!currmissTF.getText().isEmpty()) {

                                    query =
                                            query + " AND current_mission = '" + currmissTF.getText().toUpperCase() +
                                            "' ";
                                    //System.out.println(query);

                                    if (countrybox.getSelectedItem() != "SELECT COUNTRY") {

                                        query =
                                                query + " AND country = '" + countrybox.getSelectedItem().toString().toUpperCase() +
                                                "' ";
                                        //System.out.println(query);


                                    } //end of countrybox

                                } //end of currmissTF


                            } //end of aliasTF


                        } //end of ageTF


                    } //end of useridTF


                } //end of clearancebox


            } //end of surnameTF


        } //end of nameTF

    } //end of agentidTF

    query = query + " ORDER BY agent_id";
    System.out.println("ACTUALL QUERY IS: " + query);


}
```

Comment: "SQL injections, SQL injections everywhere"

Comment: You shouldn't nest your if statements from where I see it, but besides this the logic would indeed be to test any conditions in order to build your query. You may also want to offer less choices to the user if your database is not that huge...
Also, as mentionned by BackSlash, be carefull cause your code is prone to SQL injections, so you should check prepared statements.

Comment: @Lambros Your code is vulnerable to [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection), you should really [use Prepared Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html) instead of building the query like you do

Comment: that is something I can fix later I agree. But is there a simpler way to search for combinations to all these?

Comment: @Lambros Also note that `clearancebox.getSelectedItem() != "SELECT CLEARANCE"` is not the right way to compare strings. You should use `!clearencebox.getSelectedItem().equals("SELECT CLEARENCE")`

Comment: Do you intend for your first test (if (!agentidTF.getText().isEmpty()) {) to drive whether or not you even get to all the nested ifs?